# CSF Installtion issue in cPanel/WHm

Tags: cpanel, firewall, whm

I have installed csf on `cPanel/whm` successfully but my problem is when I enable `csf` firewall. It blocks all incoming and outgoing requests so, no one can open their domain name, ftp nor anything. I have no clue about it so I'd really appreciate if someone can guide me step by step to configure `csf` in `cPanel/whm`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure below setting in your csf.conf

> TESTING = "0"
>
> TESTING_INTERVAL =  Default: 5
>
> TCP_IN = 20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,2077,2078,2082,2083,2086,2087,2095,2096,26
>
> TCP_OUT = 20,21,22,25,37,43,53,80,110,113,443,587,873,2087,2089,2703,3306
>
> UDP_IN = 20,21,53
>
> UDP_OUT = 20,21,53,113,123,873,6277
>
> ICMP_IN =  Default: 1
>
> ICMP_OUT =  Default: 1
>
> SMTP_PORTS = 25 36